# Json access error

Tags: javascript

```
var markers3 = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 1964; i++) {
    var dataPhoto = data8.weblandmarks8[i];
    if(data8.weblandmarks8[i].ip2==data8.weblandmarks8[i+1].ip2 )
            {
            var k=i+2;
            while(1)
                {
                if((data8.weblandmarks8[k].ip2) == (data8.weblandmarks8[i].ip2))
                k++;
                else break;
                }   

            for (var j = i; j < k; j++)
                {
                var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data8.weblandmarks8[j].latitude,data8.weblandmarks8[j].longitude);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: latLng,icon: webicon,title:data8.weblandmarks8[j].webaddress}); 
                markers3.push(marker);  
                }   

            i=k-1;
            }

    }
```

google maps application
I get the following error in firefox

```
Error: data8.weblandmarks8[k] is undefined
Source File: file:///Applications/MAMP/htdocs/geo/js/myscript.js
Line: 140
```

I have defined `K` but why does firefox say that the json data accessed with it is undefined?
the same data can be accessed with `i` variable.

edit:
I have a json data file which I am accessing by
    
its working
but the error is with that specific line only

Comment: `k` is different from `i` (it is always larger than `i`). Make sure that `k` is always in the allowed range. And there is no JSON in your question, just JS arrays and objects.

Comment: @Felix: Do you ever post an answer as an actual answer (so you can get due credit!?) I only ever see your wisdom preached via comments!

Comment: @Matt: Look at my profile, I also gave a couple of real answers ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This calls for some basic debugging first: For what value of `k` does it fail? What happens if you try to address that value directly?

I'm fairly sure `k` (being `i+2`) simply reaches the end of the list at some point - as it stands, the code needs 1966 elements to be present in order to work.